# Mi codigo php genera un pdf pero me descarga el archivo php completo

Tags: php, pdf, hosting, composer, dompdf

Hice un pequeño formulario donde mando los datos a un archivo PHP para generar el PDF, estoy utilizando DOMPDF y COMPOSER. Cuando intento descargar el PDF de manera local lo hace de manera correcta, pero cuando subi mi proyecto a un hosting gratuito 000webhost no me descarga el PDF sino que mas bien me descarga el archivo completo de PHP.
Puede ser alguna configuración del hosting que haga falta o algo por el estilo

Si me pueden ayudar para que me descargue o se visualice el archivo pdf en vez del php.

este es mi codigo donde genero el pdf con dompdf y php:

```
<?php
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

ob_start();

$nombre = trim($_POST['nombres']);
$medico = trim($_POST['medico']);
$folio = trim($_POST['folio']);
$sexo = trim($_POST['sexo']);
$fechaServicio = trim($_POST['fecha-servicio']);
$fechaEntrega = trim($_POST['fecha-entrega']);
$horaToma = trim($_POST['hora-toma']);
$fechaNac = trim($_POST['fecha-nac']);
$edad = trim($_POST['edad']);

if (
    !empty($nombre) && !empty($medico) && !empty($folio) && !empty($sexo) && !empty($fechaServicio)
    && !empty($fechaEntrega) && !empty($horaToma) && !empty($fechaNac) && !empty($edad) && !empty($_FILES['img'])
) {
    foreach ($_FILES['img']['name'] as $key => $val) {
        $img1 = "../../imgs/logo.png";
        $img3 = "../../imgs/firma.png";
        $imagenB1 = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode(file_get_contents($img1));
        $imagenB3 = "data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode(file_get_contents($img3));

        $img_info = getimagesize($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$key]);
        $imagenB2 = "data:" . $img_info["mime"] . ";base64," . base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'][$key]));

        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">

        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Conversion PDF</title>
            <style>
                * {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                }

                body {
                    width: 100%;
                }

                p {
                    font-size: 12px;
                }

                .cont-header {
                    height: 100px;
                    background-color: rgb(107, 238, 243);
                    color: white;
                    position: relative;
                }

                .cont-header table {
                    width: 800px;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 50%;
                    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                }

                .cont-header table td {
                    margin: 10px;
                }

                .cont-dates-list {
                    height: 100px;
                    position: relative;
                }

                .cont-dates-list table {
                    width: 700px;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 50%;
                    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                }

                .cont-dates-list table td {
                    margin: 10px;
                }

                .cont-titulo {
                    text-align: center;
                }

                .cont-tel {
                    font-weight: 800;
                    margin-top: -10px;
                }

                .img-bn {
                    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
                    filter: grayscale(100%);
                }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>
            <section class="cont-header">
                <table>
                    <td>
                        <figure style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            <img src="<?php echo $imagenB1; ?>" alt="logo de mas vida" width="140">
                        </figure>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td tyle="width: 140px;">
                        <p class="cont-tel">Cel.58445213</p>
                    </td>
                </table>
            </section>
            <section class="cont-dates">
                <div class="cont-dates-list">
                    <table>
                        <td>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">PACIENTE: </span><?php echo strtoupper($nombre); ?></p>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">MÉDICO: </span><?php echo strtoupper($medico); ?></p>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">FECHA DE SERVICIO: </span><?php echo $fechaServicio; ?></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">FECHA DE ENTREGA: </span><?php echo $fechaEntrega ?></p>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">HORA DE TOMA: </span><?php echo $horaToma ?></p>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">FECHA DE NACIMIENTO: </span><?php echo $fechaNac ?></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">FOLIO: </span><?php echo $folio ?></p>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">SEXO: </span><?php echo strtoupper($sexo) ?></p>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">EDAD: </span><?php echo $edad ?></p>
                        </td>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </section>
            <hr>
            <section class="cont-result">
                <figure style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;">
                    <img class="img-bn" src="<?php echo $imagenB2; ?>" alt="imagen de los analisis" width="700">
                </figure>
            </section>
        </body>

        </html>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Conversion PDF</title>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }

            body {
                width: 100%;
            }

            p {
                font-size: 12px;
            }

            .cont-header {
                height: 100px;
                background-color: rgb(107, 238, 243);
                color: white;
                position: relative;
            }

            .cont-header table {
                width: 800px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            .cont-header table td {
                margin: 10px;
            }

            .cont-dates-list {
                height: 100px;
                position: relative;
            }

            .cont-dates-list table {
                width: 700px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            .cont-dates-list table td {
                margin: 10px;
            }

            .cont-titulo {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .cont-tel {
                font-weight: 800;
                margin-top: -10px;
            }

            .img-bn {
                -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
                filter: grayscale(100%);
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section class="cont-header">
            <table>
                <td>
                    <figure style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <img src="<?php echo $imagenB1; ?>" alt="logo de mas vida" width="140">
                    </figure>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="cont-titulo">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td tyle="width: 140px;">
                    <p class="cont-tel">Cel.5444730448</p>
                </td>
            </table>
        </section>
        <section class="cont-dates">
            <div class="cont-dates-list">
            <table>
                        <td>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">PACIENTE: </span><?php echo strtoupper($nombre); ?></p>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">MÉDICO: </span><?php echo strtoupper($medico); ?></p>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">FECHA DE SERVICIO: </span><?php echo $fechaServicio; ?></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">FECHA DE ENTREGA: </span><?php echo $fechaEntrega ?></p>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">HORA DE TOMA: </span><?php echo $horaToma ?></p>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">FECHA DE NACIMIENTO: </span><?php echo $fechaNac ?></p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">FOLIO: </span><?php echo $folio ?></p>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">SEXO: </span><?php echo strtoupper($sexo) ?></p>
                            <p><span style="font-weight:800;">EDAD: </span><?php echo $edad ?></p>
                        </td>
                    </table>
            </div>
        </section>
        <hr>
        <section class="cont-footer" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <figure style="text-align: center;">
                <img src="<?php echo $imagenB3; ?>" alt="firma de los analisis">
            </figure>
        </section>
    </body>
    </html>

<?php

    $html = ob_get_clean();

    $option = new Options();
    $option->set('isRemoteEnable', true);
    $dompdf = new Dompdf($option);
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream('RESULTADOS_' . strtoupper($nombre) . '.pdf', array('Attachment' => false));

    header('Location: ' . '../../index.html');

} else {
    echo ("Error campos vacios");
}

?>
```

Comment: estás seguro que tienes php activado en el servidor?

Comment: pues anteriormente ya he usado php en otros proyectos en ese mismo hosting y sin ningun problema, solo ahorita el problema que tengo